# How to load a file into an array in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to programming and trying to find out how to load a file into a 2d array.
there are several lines to the file.

line 1 is a test case line.
line 2 is how many rows and columns are in the array. Also whether to use left hand rules or right-hand rules.
line 3 is where the starting position is located and the finish position.

for example:
2
12 12 L
2 1 11 12

I have used T for the test cases
N for the rows, M for the columns, S for start, finish for the end

```
import java.util.*;

public class lRMaze {


    public static int [][] move = {
            {0, 1},
            {1, 0},
            {0, -1},
            {1, 0},

    };


    public static boolean east = true, north = false, south = false, west = false;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the filename.
        System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Open the file.
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int T = inputFile.nextInt();

        while (T !=0 || T < 20)
        {
            int N = inputFile.nextInt(); //number of rows in the maze
            int M = inputFile.nextInt();// number of columns in the maze
            String hand = inputFile.next(); // left-hand or right-hand
            int sR = inputFile.nextInt(); // starting position row
            int sC = inputFile.nextInt(); // starting position column
            int fR = inputFile.nextInt(); // finish row
            int fC = inputFile.nextInt(); // finish column

            char [][] field = new char [N][M];

            for (int i = 0; i <N; i++) {
                String line = inputFile.next();
                for (int j = 0; j < M; j++);{

                    field[i][j] = line.charAt(j);






        }// end while

        // Close the file.
```

I do not know where I am going wrong with this. Can someone please help?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong details loaded?

Comment: Sorry, I get a red mark on the [j] in the inner loop. So somewhere I am doing something wrong. States that it "cannot resolve j. Do I want to create a variable j."

Comment: What's the error displayed when you hover over that red mark?

Comment: "cannot resolve j. Do I want to create a variable j."

Comment: Your problem of `j` not being defined is due to the extra semicolon at the end of this line: `for (int j = 0; j < M; j++);{` - that extra semicolon means that the line that follows is not within the `for` loop, and so `j` is not defined for that line.

Comment: If you need additional help with your code, please update your question in two ways: 1) fix the code so that it is complete and compiles (having fixed the undefined `j` problem).  You're at least missing a few '}' at the end of your code, and 2) Provide a sample data file that exhibits the problem you're having.